# What's the most efficient way to detect a break in a circuit

Tags: sensor, low-power

I'm building a sensor that detects when a refridgerator door is left open. my goal is to use 2 contacts that close the circuit when the door is closed. So, when the door is opened, the contacts open and the door trigger fires. My issue is that I want it powered by batteries and therefore needs to be ultra low powered. In general, I'm using 3.3v logic and a button battery for power.

Answer (score 4):

I would reverse the logic.

Have the door switch contacts open when the door is closed - that way the alarm circuit will not draw any power when the door is closed.

When the door is opened, the switch contacts will close, powering the alarm circuit, either sounding the alarm immediately, or after a suitable delay.  When the door is closed, the switch will open, removing power from the alarm.

Comment: How would I do that? Is there a common pattern to reverse that logic?